# How can I make a nested inner join with findOne options using TypeOrm on Express?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typeorm

I have the following:

```js
    const estudios = await findOne(Estudio, {
        relations: {
            'solicitud': true,
            'area': true,
            'promotor': true,
            'propuesta': true,
        },
    });
```

Is there a way to make a nested inner join?
This is because I have relations like:
Estudio -> Propuesta (with idPropuesta on Estudio's table)
Propuesta -> TipoPropuesta (with idTipoPropuesta on Propuesta)

Right now, as I have it, my service is returning only the id of TipoPropuesta from Propuesta:

```
id: someId,
...
propuesta: {
  ...
  idTipoPropuesta: someId,
  ...
},
...
}
```

I would like to get the relation attributes as well between this Propuesta and its type.

I've tried using `"propuesta.tipoPropuesta":true` on my service but it isn't working.